# Executing a module when the user opens the page

Tags: magento2, module

I have a module that records the user's IP on the debug log when he visits the page "`example.com/iplog/index/test`".

My module is located in the app/code/IpLog folder and contains the modules.xml, registration.php, routes.xml and controller files.

Ip log example:

```
[2019-05-13 21:53:03] main.DEBUG: 127.0.0.1 05/13/2019 09:53:03 pm [] []
```

I want this action (IP logging) to happen when the user enters the main page on the site "example.com". How can I execute the module this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if controller is home page then add your logging for home page controller.

Check this link on mageplaza https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-check-current-url-homepage-magento-2.html

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

 protected $_logo;  

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $logo,
    array $data = []
)
{       
    $this->_logo = $logo;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Check if current url is url for home page
 *
 * @return bool
 */
 public function isHomePage()
 {  
    return $this->_logo->isHomePage();
 }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this other [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122365/magento-2-run-function-on-every-page) i was able to understand better what i needed to do. 
I created a file called "events.xml" and a Observer class. This way a module is able to listen to a specific event and act upon it.